# False friends? Keyword "static" in C compared to C++, C# and Java

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, history

To me, the use of the keyword `static` in C and languages like C# and Java are "false friends" like "to become" in English and "bekommen" in German (= "to get" in English), because they mean different things.

In C `static` means, that the function or variable is only accessible via functions inside the same source file, comparable to `private` functions and members in C++, Java and C#.

In C++, Java and C# `static` means, that the methods are not members of a class instance, but effectively are more or less like C functions plus namespace.

IMHO these two concepts are quite different, so why did the designers of C++ and later Java and C# choose the `static` keyword for that behaviour? Is there a logical connection that I miss?

**EDIT**
I know, that `static` in C does not govern accessability in a way similar to `private` in C++, but can be used in that way, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479639/124983

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a book about the design of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup (the inventor of C++). I don't have it right here so I can't lookup the exact quote right now, but in it he admits that when he added `static` to C++, he didn't fully understand what it meant in C. So that's why in C++ it has a different meaning than in C.

Java and C# inherited the meaning from C++.

Comment: Created an account on here just to upvote this answer! This is amazing information that I wouldn't ever wanna miss in my life as software developer!

Comment: @Maverick283 It's this book: [The Design and Evolution of C++](https://books.google.nl/books/about/The_Design_and_Evolution_of_C++.html?id=hS9mDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y)

Answer (score 14):

Notably, C++ has *both* uses of `static`, and I think there's a third somewhere.

Generally, I think that the C use of `static` does not correspond at all to any English usage of the word, whereas I think that `static` as a `static` member variable, for example, makes a lot more sense.

Remember that as a language designer, you have a fair incentive to introduce fewer keywords into the language, to disallow less code- especially when you're trying to be source-compatible with C, as in C++, and the `static` keyword already existed, so they couldn't break any C programs trying to compile as C++ by re-using it.

Edit: I knew there was a third. C has function-level `static` variables. The `static` member is just a scoped version of this functionality. Therefore, *both* uses of `static` originate from C.

Comment: c has two uses of static (linkage and lifetime), c++ has both these and the class one

Comment: @jk: The class version is the same thing as the function-level `static`, it's just scoped to a class instead of a function.

Comment: @jk. Many think of `static` having three uses in C (function scope variable, compilation unit scope for variables, compilation unit scope for functions). It really is doing the two same things in these three cases (linkage and lifetime), I share your opinion on this. The view of three uses of static in C is more common, sadly. It helps people understand how to use it, but not how it really works.

Comment: You're forgetting the new C99 usage of static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function

Comment: answer below is best: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141880/253741, but for comparison -- 2 in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/728586/1200764  -  C vs C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29224988/1200764  -  3 in C++: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

Answer (score 9):

In C++, `static` has the following **four** uses:

- **Global (file-level) function and variable declarations**: with static, you are specifying *internal linkage*. That means that the symbol is only used in that one compilation unit (.cpp/cc/whatever file, not a header). This is what you are referring to as "private".
- **Local variables**: Static *storage duration* specifies that the variable should retain its value between function calls.
- **Data members**: Static data members are shared between the instances of the class (i.e. there is only one copy of the member). This is akin to C# and Java static.
- **Member functions**: Static member functions are member functions that don't have an implicit `this` pointer; they can be invoked without an instance. This is also much like in C# or Java.

So, as you can see, they dropped two of the above meanings. For scoping it is quite understandable why: both C# and Java (and even C++) relies on namespaces to do that. C++ probably has the internal linkage feature for backwards compatibility. Ditching static local variables is probably two-folded: for once, it can be difficult to fully understand its consequences, and these languages aim for simplicity. Second, both Java and C# has a garbage collector which (I can imagine) causes difficulties to implement such behavior.

Comment: "C++ probably has the internal linkage feature for backwards compatibility." - one might add (IIRC) that the C++ Standard first deprecated this use of `static` (preferring anonymous namespaces) and then, in its current incarnation C++11 de-deprecated the use of `static` for this. (all IIRC)

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure that compilers didn't honor this deprecation then, because it worked with at least two mainstream ones (gcc and MSVC).

Comment: No compiler threw it out as far as I know. Still I think *the '98/'03 standard* deprecated it or somesuch. What I actually wanted to say with my comment was that the internal linkage thing is a feature that is apparently also considered useful in C++, so it's not only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The "c++-y" way of doing the same thing is to declare in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: "is to declare in an anonymous namespace" - except that it is not the same thing technically. (I do apologize for not having more references, but I lack the time atm. to look it up. (I think it was mentioned in the comp.lang.c++.moderated NG, and maybe one can find some reference in the standard papers of WG21 ...)

Answer (score 3):

C++ took it from C, because C++ likes to reuse existing keywords instead of introducing new ones, to minimize breaking existing code.

Java and C# then took it from C++.

Answer (score 3):

C `static` does not govern accessibility, and isn't analagous to `private` in the way you suggest.

At file scope, it governs availability of the *name* (linker symbol), *not* the thing - you can pass a pointer to a `static` function or global from the translation unit where it is defined to code in another file, and it will work fine.

The C++ way of doing this (as DeadMG says, the C way is still available too) is to use an anonymous namespace.

In function scope, it essentially replaces the local variable with a global which is only accessible (by name again!) inside that function - this is identical in C++ (so, there isn't a more *C++y*  way of doing it).

As for why C++ used the `static` qualifier for class members; it's probably right to say that this is to minimize the number of new keywords introduced. (Note the recent re-use of *auto* for comparison).

Calling per-class data *static* (so implicitly per-instance data are *dynamic*) seems fairly intuitive to me, but since I don't remember the process of forming that intuition, I can't really comment objectively on whether it made sense when starting out.